# Data retrieved from T-SQL stored procedure into C# DataTable are skewed

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, datatable

I do have a strange problem I really do not understand when I retrieve data from a T-SQL stored procedure into a C# DataTable. The result I get in T-SQL is different from the result the DataTable shown after the data has been retrieved. Different data means that cells in the DataTable are either missing rows, or showing different data.

Here is the code I am using in C#

```
public DataTable  GetData()
{
    string nameOfSp = "sp_SIA_Get_Ratio_Demand_Receipt";

    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dataAccess.OpenDatabase(DataAccess.ConnectionTo.SQL);

    SqlConnection sqlCon = dataAccess.GetSqlConnection();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(nameOfSp, sqlCon);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@COMPANY", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter.CompanyNo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@YEARWEEK_FROM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter.YearWeekFrom;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@YEARWEEK_TO", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter.YearWeekTo;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filter.UserName;

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not retrieve data from stored procedure " + ex.Message);
    }

    dataAccess.CloseDatabase();

    return dt;
}
```

And here is the SQL statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SIA_Get_Ratio_Demand_Receipt]
    @COMPANY as varchar(4),
    @USERNAME as varchar(50),
    @YEARWEEK_FROM as varchar(6),
    @YEARWEEK_TO as varchar(6)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH #MATERIAL (COMPANY_NO, MATERIAL_NO, STORAGE_LOCATION, INVENTORY_QTY, INVENTORY_VAL) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            p.COMPANY_NO, p.ITEM_NO, p.STORAGE_LOCATION, 
            SUM(STOCK_QUANTITY), SUM(STOCK_VALUE)
        FROM  
            tbl_SIA_Sel_PartNos p 
        INNER JOIN 
            [FUM_DWH].[dbo].[View_SCM_FACT_610_WAREHOUSE_STOCK] s ON p.ITEM_NO = s.ITEM_NO
                                                                  AND p.COMPANY_NO = s.COMPANY_NO
                                                                  AND p.STORAGE_LOCATION = s.STORAGE_LOCATION
        WHERE 
            p.USERNAME = @USERNAME
            AND s.YEARWEEK =@YEARWEEK_TO
            AND p.ITEM_NO IN( '50048348') --p.ITEM_NO IN( '50057896','50048348','50293653','50059293')
        GROUP BY 
            p.COMPANY_NO, p.ITEM_NO, p.STORAGE_LOCATION
    )
        
    ,#DEMAND (COMPANY_NO, MATERIAL_NO, STORAGE_LOCATION, DEMAND_QTY) AS
    (
        SELECT  
            STRI_COMPANY_NO,
            STRI_ITEM_NO,
            STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION,
            SUM(STRI_QUANTITY * -1) AS DEMAND_QTY
        FROM 
            #MATERIAL m 
        INNER JOIN 
            [FUM_DWH].[dbo].[View_SCM_FACT_620_PAST_STOCK_RECEIPT_ISSUE] p ON m.MATERIAL_NO = p.STRI_ITEM_NO 
                                               AND p.STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION = m.STORAGE_LOCATION
        WHERE 
            STRI_COMPANY_NO = @COMPANY 
            AND CONCAT(STRI_YEAR, FORMAT( STRI_WEEK, '00')) BETWEEN @YEARWEEK_FROM AND @YEARWEEK_TO
            AND STRI_DEBIT_CREDIT = 'H' --nur Abgänge werten
        GROUP BY 
            STRI_ITEM_NO, STRI_COMPANY_NO, STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION
    )
    , #RECEIPT(COMPANY_NO, MATERIAL_NO, STORAGE_LOCATION, RECEIPT_QTY) AS
    (
        SELECT  
            STRI_COMPANY_NO,
            STRI_ITEM_NO,
            STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION,
            SUM(STRI_QUANTITY) AS RECEIPT_QTY
        FROM 
            [FUM_DWH].[dbo].[View_SCM_FACT_620_PAST_STOCK_RECEIPT_ISSUE] p 
        INNER JOIN 
            #MATERIAL m ON p.STRI_ITEM_NO = m.MATERIAL_NO 
                        AND p.STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION = m.STORAGE_LOCATION
        WHERE 
            STRI_COMPANY_NO = @COMPANY
            AND CONCAT(STRI_YEAR, FORMAT(STRI_WEEK, '00')) BETWEEN      @YEARWEEK_FROM AND @YEARWEEK_TO
            AND STRI_DEBIT_CREDIT = 'S' --nur Zugänge werten 
        GROUP BY 
            STRI_ITEM_NO, STRI_COMPANY_NO,STRI_STORAGE_LOCATION
    )
    ,#DEMAND_FUT (MATERIAL_NO, STORAGE_LOCATION, DEMAND_QTY, DEMAND_VAL) AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            [ITEM_NO], s.STORAGE_LOCATION,
            SUM([QUANTITY]) * -1 AS DEMAND_QTY,
            SUM([VALUE]) * -1 AS DEMAND_VAL
        FROM 
            [FUM_DWH].[dbo].[View_SCM_FACT_630_FUTURE_STOCK_RECEIPT_ISSUE] s 
        INNER JOIN 
            #MATERIAL m ON m.MATERIAL_NO = s.ITEM_NO 
                        AND m.STORAGE_LOCATION = s.STORAGE_LOCATION 
        WHERE 
            s.COMPANY_NO = @COMPANY
            AND TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(day, 31, GETDATE())
        GROUP BY 
            ITEM_NO, s.STORAGE_LOCATION
    )
    SELECT  
        m.MATERIAL_NO, 
        ISNULL(SUM(d.DEMAND_QTY), 1) AS PST_DEMAND_QTY, 
        ISNULL(SUM(r.RECEIPT_QTY), 1) AS PST_RECEIPT_QTY, 
        ISNULL(SUM(r.RECEIPT_QTY), 1) / ISNULL(SUM(d.DEMAND_QTY), 1) AS RATIO,
        SUM(m.INVENTORY_QTY) AS INVENTORY_QTY, 
        SUM(m.INVENTORY_VAL) AS INVENTORY_VAL, 
        ISNULL(SUM(f.DEMAND_QTY), 0) AS FUT_DEMAND_QTY, 
        ISNULL(SUM(f.DEMAND_VAL), 0) AS FUT_DEMAND_VAL,
        ISNULL(SUM(m.INVENTORY_QTY) - SUM(f.DEMAND_QTY), 0) AS  RMN_INVENTORY_QTY, 
        ISNULL(SUM(m.INVENTORY_VAL) - SUM(f.DEMAND_VAL), 0) AS RMN_INVENTORY_VAL
    FROM 
        #MATERIAL m 
    LEFT JOIN 
        #DEMAND d ON m.MATERIAL_NO = d.MATERIAL_NO 
                  AND m.STORAGE_LOCATION = d.STORAGE_LOCATION
    LEFT JOIN 
        #RECEIPT r ON m.MATERIAL_NO = r.MATERIAL_NO 
                   AND m.STORAGE_LOCATION = r.STORAGE_LOCATION
    LEFT JOIN 
        #DEMAND_FUT f ON m.MATERIAL_NO = f.MATERIAL_NO 
                      AND m.STORAGE_LOCATION = f.STORAGE_LOCATION
    GROUP BY 
        m.MATERIAL_NO 
    ORDER BY 
        m.MATERIAL_NO -- ISNULL(SUM(r.RECEIPT_QTY), 1) / ISNULL(SUM(d.DEMAND_QTY), 1) DESC
END
```

The result I get from the SQL statement:

[image]

The result I get from the DataTable:

[image]

I changed my code in C# back from async as I thought this would case the issue.

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The DataTable class doesn't mangle data. There's no if or but or maybe. Either you called the wrong stored procedure (or stored procedure) or posted the wrong results. ADO.NET and DataReader classes are used for *all* data access in .NET since the very first version. If there was a problem, every .NET developer would have noticed in the last 22 years. The fact the column names are different means the results come from a different query

Comment: Capture the .NET call in SQL Profiler and compare.

Comment: BTW The query code is unusual and definitely slow - there's no reason to use `#` in CTE names and the nested groupings will force the database to repeatedly store intermediate results in tempdb. If this query is used in a data warehouse, it will take a *very* long time to run and scan the entire fact table, without using indexes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that‘s what my experience is as well.  I run a couple of sp‘s that way and have never seen such an issue. The column names are the same. They look different because they are cut in the snapshot and I can ensure I call the right sp.

Comment: @marc_s ok will follow that advise but in this case unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft would you mind to explain to me how to capture the .NET call in SQL profiler?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok will follow that advise but I thought temp tables are just stored when created by CREATE and the actual variable name of an WITH statement is irrelevant.

Comment: It is irrelevant. I was asking why you used that name. Tempdb will be used to store intermediary query results if needed, no matter what aliases are used. If you check the query's execution plan I suspect you'll see that the CTE results get spooled into tempdb, because those results have to be known before the next CTE or JOIN is evaluated. It's possible that this query will result in 1 full table scan per CTE.

Comment: Another possible problem is that the *SqlCommand parameters* get truncated because they have no size. The stored procedure uses some rather weird string manipulations, eg `CONCAT(STRI_YEAR, FORMAT(STRI_WEEK, '00')) BETWEEN      @YEARWEEK_FROM` that would produce different results if the values were concatenated. That condition forces a full table scan as well and can't use any indexes. Data warehouses always use a Calendar or DateDimension table with eg 50 years of precalculated dates with additional indexed columns like year, month, week, reporting period, to avoid such manipulations

Comment: Run a trace in SQL Server Profiler. You can filter down to specific events to capture and filter on database etc. If you don't have it installed I *think* it comers bundled with SQL Server Management Studio (there is a menu option to launch profiler from SSMS at least). Its just  an app you connect to your sql server with and then you can trace all the activity so you'll be able to see exactly what command was sent to the server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your advise regarding my SQL string CONCAT(STRI_YEAR, FORMAT(STRI_WEEK, '00')) eventually caused that problem. Once corrected my DataTable shows the same result as the result from the strored procedure. Thank you so much! However what I still do not understand is why the results can be different? I have always thought that the stored procedure returns the same result to e.g., a DataTable as if the store procedure were called in SQL Studion which is apparently not the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are calling a stored procedure named sp_SIA_Get_Ratio_Demand_Receipt The WHERE clause is causing the discrepancy. To see what is being sent to SQL server you can use a profiler like SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Yes you are right I just showed the Select part but now have updated my question with the entire stored procedure statement.

Comment: Now we need to know the filter values for  COMPANY,  USERNAME,    YEARWEEK_FROM,  and YEARWEEK_TO.   Your SQL command will be  like EXEC sp_SIA_Get_Ratio_Demand_Receipt 'company', 'Chris', '202001', '202002'

Comment: These are exactly the filter values I am using. The values are different but all are varchars.

Comment: When you try the command EXEC sp_SIA_Get_Ratio_Demand_Receipt 'company', 'Chris', '202001', '202002'  (instead of the query) do the results match your grid?  It should because that appears to be the command used by the Data Adapter to fill the DataTable.